# How to speed up parsing of Apache log with RegEx to expand the Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing

I am writing a script which parses big(400mb) apache log files into a pandas table.

My old laptop parses the apache log file with the script in about 2minutes. 
Now I am wondering if it could not be faster?

The apache log file structure is like this: 
Ip - - [timestamp] “GET … method” http-status-code bytes “address” “useragent”
For example:

```
93.185.11.11 - - [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200] "GET /v1/con?from=…" 200 575 "http://google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

My code uses regex findall. I also testet with the match and search method. But they seem to be slower.

```
 reg_dic = {
    "ip" : r'\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b',
    "timestamp" : r'\[\d+\/\w+\/\d+\:\d+\:\d+\:\d+\s\+\d+\]',
    "method" : r'"(.*?)"',
    "httpstatus" : r'\s\d{1,3}\s',
    "bytes_" : r'\s\d+\s\"',
    "adress" : r'\d\s\"(.*?)"',
    "useragent" : r'\"\s\"(.*?)"'
}

    for name, reg in reg_dic.items() : 
        item_list = [] 
        with open ( file ) as f_obj: 
            for line in f_obj : 
                item = re.findall( reg , line) 
                item = item[0]
                if name == "bytes_" : 
                    item = item.replace("\"", "")
                item = item.strip()
                item_list.append( item )
        df[ name ] = item_list
        del item_list
```

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/LLW3Uf) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UOtsAL/1). If your log lines are always of the same format, this should be fast and safe enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `expand` paramter true so that will return a dataframe based on extracted data. Hope it helps

Example df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"log":['93.185.11.11 - - [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 
+0200] "GET /v1/con?from=…" 200 575 "http://google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 
(Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"',

'93.185.11.11 - - [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200] "GET /v1/con?from=…" 
200 575 "http://google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; 
rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"',

'93.185.11.11 - - [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200] "GET /v1/con?from=…" 
200 575 "http://google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; 
rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"']})
```

This is based on @ [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) 's regex improvement

```
ws = '^(?P<ip>[\d.]+)(?:\s+\S+){2}\s+\[(?P<timestamp>[\w:/\s+]+)\]\s+"(?P<method>[^"]+)"\s+(?P<httpstatus>\d+)\s+(?P<bytes>\d+)\s+(?P<adress>"[^"]+")\s+(?P<useragent>"[^"]+")$'

new = df['log'].str.extract(ws,expand=True)
```

Output:

```
             ip                   timestamp              method httpstatus  \
0  93.185.11.11  13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…        200   
1  93.185.11.11  13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…        200   
2  93.185.11.11  13/Aug/2016:05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…        200   

  bytes               adress  \
0   575  "http://google.com"   
1   575  "http://google.com"   
2   575  "http://google.com"   

                                           useragent  
0  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) ...  
1  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) ...  
2  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need too much RegEx's for this simple task:

```
fn = r'D:\temp\.data\46620093.log'
cols = ['ip','l','userid','timestamp','tz','request','status','bytes','referer','useragent']

df = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, names=cols).drop('l', 1)
```

which gives us:

```
In [179]: df
Out[179]:
             ip userid              timestamp      tz             request  \
0  93.185.11.11      -  [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12  +0200]  GET /v1/con?from=…
1  93.185.11.11      -  [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12  +0200]  GET /v1/con?from=…
2  93.185.11.11      -  [13/Aug/2016:05:34:12  +0200]  GET /v1/con?from=…

   status  bytes            referer  \
0     200    575  http://google.com
1     200    575  http://google.com
2     200    575  http://google.com

                                           useragent
0  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
2  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
```

now we just need to concatenate `timestamp` and `tz` into one column and get rid of `[` and `]`:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.replace(r'\[(\d+/\w+/\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+)', r'\1 \2') \
                    + ' ' + df.pop('tz').str.strip(r'[\]]')
```

Result:

```
In [181]: df
Out[181]:
             ip userid                   timestamp             request  \
0  93.185.11.11      -  13/Aug/2016 05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…
1  93.185.11.11      -  13/Aug/2016 05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…
2  93.185.11.11      -  13/Aug/2016 05:34:12 +0200  GET /v1/con?from=…

   status  bytes            referer  \
0     200    575  http://google.com
1     200    575  http://google.com
2     200    575  http://google.com

                                           useragent
0  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
2  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:54.0) G...
```

NOTE: we can easily convert `datetime` into `datetime` dtype (in UTC time without time zone):

```
In [182]: pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
Out[182]:
0   2016-08-13 03:34:12
1   2016-08-13 03:34:12
2   2016-08-13 03:34:12
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```